# How can I control the EXE name based on the target platform?

Tags: delphi, build, exe

I'd like to have two different exe files, depending on whether it's 32-bit or 64-bit build, e.g., FooBar32.exe and FooBar64.exe. Is there a way to set this or is this going to be a postbuild action?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Project options under the Application tab there is a setting to change the target file extension. You can use this to change the name of executable of your project for different platforms.
NOTE: This only extends the default name that would be created (project name + Target file extension)

[image]

EDIT: As you can see this approach has one drawback and that is that it always add a dot in between the Project name and Target file extension.

But to be honest I rather follow the approach where I configure Delphi to output 32 bit executables in Bin32 and 64 bil executables into Bin64 folder instead of even renaming the main executable. Why?

If your application is using any external dynamic link libraries (dll's) you need to make sure to have them for each suported platform (32 bit executables require 32 bit dll's, while 64 bit executables require 64 bit dll's).

So if you store all these dll's in a single folder you will have to make sure that they are properly named (all 32 bit dll's would have 32 prefix and all 64 bit dll's would have 64 prefix). But that also means that in your code you would need to have specific entries for importing functions from these dll's (one for 32 bit dll and one for 64 bit dll). And that can realy complicate everything.

So making seperate bin folders for 32 bit and 64 bit application versions alows you to have dll's for 32 bit and 64 bit applications with the same names and therefore no need to make any changes in your source code to be able to handle with 32 bit and 64 bit dll's

Comment: Good points and this is certainly one way to go with it and it answers my question on how to do this within the IDE.  I don't know if I like the idea of the extra dot, however. FWIW, this EXE renaming is more of a customer requirement and when installed on a customer machine, they would be installed into program files or program files (x86). My build environment does use Win32 and Win64 folders.

Comment: If you intent on installing the application into different folders on the target machine then it is definitly best to use separate bin folders than renaming the executable as it would be easier for you to make final packages or instalation program.

Comment: As far as "program files" and "program files (x86)" folders goes by my opinion Microsoft just made huge confusion with them. Why? It is logical which folder you chose if you distribute only 32 bit or 64 bit version of your software. But what if you are distributing both versions of your software at the same time? Where do you install the software now? In "program files" or in "program files (x86)" folder. Well you could install binary files in both folders but then how do you deal with location of other data files that your application might use? You see lots of confusion for nothing.

Comment: I deploy 32 and 64 bit versions. Since they share aux files I put them in the same folder with different names. I put them under the 32 bit program files folder.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly what you need, but may be it helps:

```
{$IFDEF WIN32}
{$EXTENSION 32.exe}
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF WIN64}
{$EXTENSION 64.exe}
{$ENDIF}
```

So, your executables will be `Foobar.32.exe` and `Foobar.64.exe` (with two dots).

Comment: This is similar as the approach I have shown with only difference that you define the extensions in your dpr file instead of inside project options.

Comment: Yes, but I prefer to set options in source code as much as it allowed by language.

Comment: Well each has its own preference

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to set this or is this going to be a postbuild action?

To the best of my knowledge, you cannot use project options to vary the output file name for different target architectures. So, you need to modify the output file name post-build.

For debug purposes you should not, and do not need to rename the executable file. The debugger won't like it if you do. So, deployment is the time to rename.

Comment: A note of caution when using post-build scripts. Do not rename executable file but make a copy instead. Why? If you rename the file you prevent debuger from launching your application since the executable file with default name no longer exists.

Comment: I agree that deployment is the best time to rename, but initialy in your answer you have been mentioning post-build

Comment: @silver deployment happens after the build. Post means after.

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time by having two projects under the project group: `FooBar32.exe` and `FooBar64.exe`. `FooBar32.exe` is set with 32-bit options and `FooBar64.exe` is set with 64-bit options. Each of the projects share the same units. The easiest way is to create `FooBar32.exe` with all the necessary files, then create `FooBar64.exe`, highlight the `FooBar32.exe` files and drag them to `FooBar64.exe`.  Changes to any of the files affect both projects since they refer to the same files. Just do a Build All from the project group to build both at the same time.